# CKAN Project - Web Framework

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons, ckan

Quick question. What web-app framework is CKAN using? I saw Pylons but that project is now deprecated for Pyramid. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Additionally, what framework does CKAN use to generate plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the authors. There are a couple of wiki posts that indicate a migration to Flask

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Migration-from-Pylons-to-Flask
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Flask-Migration-Roadmap

Comment: There is an ongoing migration to Flask. If you download the current master version, it is actually using Pylons (a migration to Pyramid never took place) and Flask behind the scenes.